# Getting tuple of objects and list from Slick 2 query

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, slick-2.0, play-slick

I have this query that should get a list of message with its sender info and their list of recipients (consider ***groupID*** and ***senderID*** function parameters):

```
(for {
    groupUsers <- Users.users if targets.groupID === groupID
    mRecipients <- recipients if mRecipients.targetID === groupUsers.id
    message <- messages if message.senderID === groupUsers.id || message.id === mRecipients.messageID
    sender <- Users.users if sender.id === m.senderID
} yield (message, sender ,mRecipients)).list.map{ result => new FullMessage(result ._1, result ._2, result ._3) }
```

But as result I got a tuple of **(Message, User, Recipient)** when I wanted to have a tuple of **(Message, User, List[Recipient])**. How do I manage to get such result?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is `recipients` and `messages` ?? Need to know more about them. This question is kind of incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Well... the code will produce the output according to what you wrote and not according to what you want. Focus on this part...

```
yield (message, sender ,mRecipients)
```

You are yielding a tuple of `(message, sender, mRecipents)`

And you did this inside the for comprehension

```
mRecipients <- recipients if mRecipients.targetID === targetID
message <- messages if message.senderID === senderID || message.id === mRecipients.messageID
sender <- Users.users if sender.id === m.senderID
```

Here each of the expressions like `recipients if mRecipients.targetID === targetID` evaluates to a `Query` monad.

To understand whats wrong with this, It is very similar to following and lets think what happens when we do this,

```
scala>:pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish

for{
  i <- List( 1, 2, 3 )
  j <- List( 1, 2, 3 )
  k <- List( 1, 2, 3 )
} yield( i, j, k )

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res1: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), (1,2,1),
(1,2,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,1), (1,3,2), (1,3,3), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,1,3),
(2,2,1), (2,2,2), (2,2,3), (2,3,1), (2,3,2), (2,3,3), (3,1,1), (3,1,2),
(3,1,3), (3,2,1), (3,2,2), (3,2,3), (3,3,1), (3,3,2), (3,3,3))
```

In simple terms, `for comprehensions` do something similar to unwraping the `monad` and get the iterator of the values inside it... and then it wraps the yielded value into the `monad` again.

So, if you do soemthing like,

```
scala>:pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish

for{
  l <- Some( List( 1, 2, 3 ) )
  i <- Some( 1 )
} yield ( l, i ) 

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
res1: Option[(List[Int], Int)] = Some((List(1, 2, 3),1))
```

Also... Your data model feels kind of wrong.

What is `recipients` ?? Tell me that and may be I will be able to solve your problem in a better and efficient way.

But considering what I can guess about your data model, now if you want list of recipients the right way, you will have to do something like,

```
// List[ ( Message, List[ Recipients] ) ]
val messageAndRecipentsList = ( for {

  // First get all possible recipents
  possibleRecipient <- recipients if possibleRecipient.targetID === targetID

  // Now get all relevant messages for sender and possibleRecipeint
  message <- messages if message.senderID === senderID || message.id === possibleRecipient.messageID

  // Now get list of recipents for each of these messages
  messageRecipients <- for {
    messageRecipient <- recipients if messageRecipient.messageID === message.id
  } yield ( messageRecipient ).list

} yield ( message, messageRecipients ) ).list

// Now lets add sender for each of these messages, I am guessing sender
// should be exactly one for each sendorId. So... instead of querying for
// same user for every message lets just query it once and add to every
// tuple of the above list,

val sender = ( for {
  sender <- Users.users if sender.id === senderID
} yield sender ).list.head


val finalList = messageAndRecipentsList.map ( {
  case ( message, msaageRecipents ) => new FullMessage( message, sender, messageRecipients )
} )
```

Comment: Edited the question. It seems like I can't use .list in a query inside a query. It gives me nothing as result on the parent query if I use it.